# How is a local tracking branch created for a remote tracking branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

`remotes/origin/feature1` is a remote tracking branch without a local tracking branch:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  mongodbutils
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/mongodbutils
  remotes/origin/feature1
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mongodbutils
```

When I check out a nonexistent branch `feature1`, why is a local tracking branch automatically created for the remote tracking branch `remotes/origin/feature1`? Is the correspondence between the remote tracking branch and the newly created local tracking branch configured or configurable and how?

When and how is a local tracking branch created for a remote tracking branch in general?

Is checking out a nonexistent branch with a name the same as the basename of a remote tracking branch the only way to create a local tracking branch for the remote tracking branch?

```
$ git checkout feature1
Branch 'feature1' set up to track remote branch 'feature1' from 'myremote'.
Switched to a new branch 'feature1'

$ git branch -a
* feature1
  master
  mongodbutils
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/mongodbutils
  remotes/origin/feature1
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mongodbutils
```

Comment: What did you *expect* to happen when you checked out a branch that already existed on the remote? If you wanted to create a *new* branch, you could have used the `-b` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an explicit passage about this built-in mechanism in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---track) (in git checkout page) :

> If no -b option is given, the name of the new branch will be derived from the remote-tracking branch, by looking at the local part of the refspec configured for the corresponding remote, and then stripping the initial part up to the "*". This would tell us to use "hack" as the local branch when branching off of "origin/hack" (or "remotes/origin/hack", or even "refs/remotes/origin/hack"). If the given name has no slash, or the above guessing results in an empty name, the guessing is aborted. You can explicitly give a name with -b in such a case.

Also, it's really convenient, and you're always free to use `-b` when you need it, as pointed out by jonrsharpe in his comment.

Finally, to answer your comment about configuration, this other [passage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#_description) in git branch page :

> When a local branch is started off a remote-tracking branch, Git sets up the branch (specifically the branch.<name>.remote and branch.<name>.merge configuration entries) so that git pull will appropriately merge from the remote-tracking branch. This behavior may be changed via the global branch.autoSetupMerge configuration flag. That setting can be overridden by using the --track and --no-track options, and changed later using git branch --set-upstream-to.

Comment: Thanks. Is `--track` on by default for `git checkout`?

Comment: @Tim Yeah good follow-up, there's a config option for that, I'm editing my answer to add this point.